# Searching a array for a specified value in a certain field

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, performance

I have the following code and want to enhance the performance (maybe with LINQ expressions?).
Anyways, it should search a array for th first item whose field with the name `fieldname` equals the passed object `obj`. 
For example, lets say we have a array with items of type `Person` with the fields `Name` and `Age`. Now I want to know if my array of 369 persons contains a person with the name "barbara streisand". Is there a faster way than what I'm doing, or even a way without using a loop?

Heres my code:

```
 public static bool ContainsField<T>(this IEnumerable<T> array, string fieldname, object obj)
    {
        foreach(T val in array)
        {
            if (val.GetType().GetField(fieldname).GetValue(val).Equals(obj))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: The question is do you really need reflection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not without a loop being involved *somewhere*, no. LINQ makes the code much easier to *read*, of course.

If all the values in the array will be of the same type, there's no need to get the field on each iteration of the loop though:

```
public static bool ContainsField<T>(this IEnumerable<T> array,
                                    string fieldname,
                                    object obj)
{
    Field field = typeof(T).GetField(fieldName);
    return array.Any(x => field.GetValue(x).Equals(obj));
}
```

This is using *less* reflection per iteration, so it'll be faster than your original, but you *could* make it faster by creating a delegate from the `Field`, to extract the value quickly. The code would end up being a lot more complicated, but probably significantly faster too.

Do you definitely *have* to specify the field name as a string instead of (say) using a lambda expression?

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is only going to hide the loop in prettier code; it won't make it faster. The real slowness in that loop is the reflection. If the caller could express the field at compile-time, that would help (and no need for your method, really):

```
bool containsAny = source.Any(item => item.SomeField == "some value");
```

However, if the caller only knows the field **name**, you could do something similar with meta-programming. A reasonable starter might be:

```
public static bool ContainsField<T>(this IEnumerable<T> array,
    string fieldname, object obj)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var member = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, fieldname);
    var body = Expression.Equal(member, Expression.Constant(obj, member.Type));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T,bool>>(body, param);
    return array.Any(lambda.Compile());
}
```

example usage:

```
static void Main()
{
    var data = new[] { new{x = 123}, new{x = 456}, new{x = 789}};
    var has = data.ContainsField("x", 789);// true
}
```

for *maximum* performance, you'd want to cache the compiled lambdas per-type

Comment: I tried `source.Any(item => item.SomeField == "some value");` but its still too slow for my needs, is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: I would appreciate every suggestion, because I really need a fast implementation, if needed I will make a method for every possible type and then make the CLR do the lookup via `dynamic`

Comment: @alex - that is a flat loop without reflection. If that doesn't do it, you'll have to pre-index, for example by creating a dictionary, hashset or lookup or the data you want to check.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var containsField = array.Any(item => item.Name == "barbara streisand");
```

Comment: Its very complicated to explain the reason _why_ I want to do this with reflection instead of using Any(...) : )

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to be calling ContainsField many times over the same array?  If so, you could make a 
`Dictionary < object, T >`
on the first pass and then use the dictionary for all the subsequent checks.  This is no good if you only call ContainsField once per array.

For instance:

        `private Dictionary < object, T > dictionary = null;
        public bool ContainsField(IEnumerable < T > array, string fieldname, object obj)
        {
            if (dictionary == null) // first call, build dictionary
            {
                dictionary = new Dictionary< object, T >();
                foreach (T val in array)
                    dictionary[val.GetType().GetField(fieldname).GetValue(val)] = val;
            }
            return dictionary.ContainsKey(obj); // every call use dictionary
        }`

You need to be careful to set dictionary = null each time you switch to a different array or a different fieldname, but you should get the idea.

Also, I recommend you change ContainsField to be a non-static method since it depends on a member field to persist the dictionary between calls.

Comment: I call ContainsField about 100.000 times on the same array to see, always with another value.

Comment: I revised my example.  See above.  This should perform much better than any kind of one-loop-per-search method.